# Short story about scorpion like creature that paralyzes and eats still living prey

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was in a sci fi anthology from the 60's or 70's. A group of campers came across a alien egg. It hatches a scorpion like alien that makes a chittering sound when it moves. There is a scene were it stings a camper and slowly eats the man who is still alive but paralyzed. The remaining campers kill the creature by setting it on fire. The story was set on a farm. The story was in an anthology found in the harbor college library in Wilmington Ca. It might still be located there. Can anyone can tell me anything more about the story or the name?

Comment: I removed your e-mail address from the question. Including it is likely to attract spam. In any case, we expect users to reply by posting an answer here.